# AlertDialog with 2 textBox doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a listener invoked when the user wants to add a new item,
the listener should show an AlertDialog with 2 EditText in this form

```
-AlertDialog Title
-AlertDialog Message
-TextView 1 above EditText1
-EditText1
-TextView 2 above EditText2
-EditText 2
```

two buttons

```
-*Cancel* on the left
-*Add* on the right
```

My code is

```
OnClickListener addNewItemListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MyActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle(R.string.add_title);
            alert.setMessage(R.string.add_message);
                    final TextView t1 = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                      t1.setText("Name");
            final EditText input1 = new EditText(MyActivity.this);
                    final TextView t2 = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                    t2.setText("Value");
            final EditText input2 = new EditText(MyActivity.this);
                    alert.setView(t1);
            alert.setView(input1);
                    alert.setView(t2);
            alert.setView(input2);
            alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                        }
                    });
            alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.add,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            try {
                                String name = input1.getText().toString();
                                double value = Double.parseDouble(input2
                                        .getText().toString());
                                addItem(name, value);
                            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                Alerts.DatiErrati(MyActivity.this);
                            }

                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
        }
    };
```

but unfortunately I get an AlertDialog with only a EditText and two button despite my original intent

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include multiple widgets in a LinearLayout and use setView to final Layout

Try this

```
OnClickListener addNewItemListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MyActivity.this);

                LinearLayout myLayout= new LinearLayout(MyActivity.this);
                myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                alert.setTitle(R.string.add_title);
                alert.setMessage(R.string.add_message);

                final TextView t1 = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                t1.setText("Name");
                final EditText input1 = new EditText(MyActivity.this);
                final TextView t2 = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                t2.setText("Value");
                final EditText input2 = new EditText(MyActivity.this);
                myLayout.addView(t1);
                myLayout.addView(input1);
                myLayout.addView(t2);
                myLayout.addView(input2);
                alert.setView(myLayout);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                            }
                        });
                alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.add,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                try {
                                    String name = input1.getText().toString();
                                    double value = Double.parseDouble(input2
                                            .getText().toString());
                                    addItem(name, value);
                                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                    Alerts.DatiErrati(MyActivity.this);
                                }

                            }
                        });
                alert.show();
            }
        };
```

Comment: just for correction did you missed myLayout.addView(input2).and i appreciated for your answaer.

Answer (score 1):

You can display your `AlertDialog` by  creating a `custom dialog`
**for example**
here the layout for the dialog **myalertdialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="+@id/myLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_hight="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
android:id="+@id/myTextView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView1"/>
<EditText
android:id="+@id=myeditText1'
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
android:id="+@id/myTextView2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView2"/>
<EditText
android:id="+@id=myeditText2'
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then inside your code

```
AlertDialog dialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflator inflater=getLayoutInflator();
View dialogView=inflator.inflate(R.layougt.myalertdialog,(ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
dialogView.setView(dialogView);
alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                        }
                    });
            alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.add,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                        }
                    });
dialog=builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

go through the link [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/edit_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"  >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_your_name" android:text="Your name" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_your_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:inputType=”text”
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java file

```
public class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener {

public interface EditNameDialogListener {
    void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText);
}

private EditText mEditText;

public EditNameDialog() {
    // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
    mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
    getDialog().setTitle("Hello");

    // Show soft keyboard automatically
    mEditText.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {
        // Return input text to activity
        EditNameDialogListener activity = (EditNameDialogListener) getActivity();
        activity.onFinishEditDialog(mEditText.getText().toString());
        this.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a separate xml layout for your alert... The problem is with alert.setView(view); 
There is difference between setView(view) and addView(view);

Comment: I have never tried to use AlertDialog with a separate xml layout, could you give me a sample?

Comment: addView(view) adds a new view in your layout while keeping the already added views. However, setView(view) sets the view of layout, thereby overriding the previous view.

Comment: I have tried but I cannot find any addView(view) method alert.addView(view) doesn't compile

Comment: That is because alertDialogs do not have addView(view) method.. And yes, I've a code of alertDialog with xml layout. But, that's quite complex. Actually I've used alertDialog to show power boosters in my game.